# Buridan’s Sentences in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, terminology

Good evening community,

I am trying to make a World that makes all of Buridan’s Sentences right. Those are Buridan’s Sentences and my trial, (all true but the sixth):[image]

Does any one have an idea why is the 6th sentence wrong

Thank you 
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dodecahedron between two tetrahedra ... you don't have that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVo28.png /// 8 is wrong now

Comment: @markjohn that's because the tetrahedronn the front is large, rather than medium

Comment: @markjohn Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your time

Comment: @markjohn Great! ... how's the course going?  Feeling like you get better at this stuff?

Comment: well, I am reading the book more now. That is helping me

Comment: I have another question, really! Why do you care to answer people's questions on this website?

Comment: @markjohn Hmm, why do people help out in general? ... I guess there is some further and deep biological reason for that, but personally, I just like to help! People go to this website with questions, and some of those I can answer, and it's nice to know I can help out.

Comment: Well, God bless you!